# Instantiating a subclass from a superclass

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following python code that creates a polymorphic structure in a MySQL DB using SQLAlchemy.

```
class Animal(Base):
    key = Column(Integer(), Sequence("My Counter" ,1 ,1), primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String())
    discriminator = Column('type',String())
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on':discriminator}

    def __init__(self,key,name):
        self.key = key
        self.name = name

class Cat(Animal):
    __tablename__ = 'cat'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'cat'}
    def walk():
        pass

class Dog(Animal):
    __tablename__ = 'dog'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'dog'}

    def walk():
         pass
```

I was wondering what the best way is to load it such that:

```
a = Animal(key=1)
c = a.create()
```

c would now be a Cat or a Dog object depending on what type it is. The Animal table has this information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you query the database using sqlalchemy. In order to get an Animal for specific key all you need to do is to perform:

```
my_key = 1
a = session.query(Animal).get(my_key)
# sqlalchemy will figure out the type automatically and will return object of proper class 
assert type(a) in (Cat, Dog,)
```

*Please note that the model your provided is incomplete.* The one below should be a complete working one:

```
class Animal(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'animal'
    key = Column(Integer(), Sequence("My Counter" ,1 ,1), primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String())
    discriminator = Column('type',String())
    __mapper_args__ = { 'polymorphic_on':discriminator, }

    def __init__(self,key,name):
        self.key = key
        self.name = name

class Cat(Animal):
    __tablename__ = 'cat'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'cat'}
    key = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('animal.key'), primary_key = True)

    def walk(self):
        print "cat walking"

class Dog(Animal):
    __tablename__ = 'dog'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'dog'}
    key = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('animal.key'), primary_key = True)

    def walk(self):
        print "dog walking"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I got it all to work. I just hoped I might be able to do something like:
    a = Animal(1)
so i didn't have to keep write "session.query..." every time I wanted to get an object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know exactly how to apply this to what you wrote, but I have done something similar.

You will want to create a factory function; this will probably be in your base class, though it could probably be separate. in any case, it needs to be a static function, so if you include it in your class, declare it `@staticmethod`.

Second, you can access the `__subclasses__` method e.g. `BaseClass.__subclasses__()` to get a list of actual subclasses of `BaseClass`. In my case, I scanned the subclasses looking for one that had a specific class attribute and then called its init function.